# how many different triangle can be formed with the given length

Tags: java

I want to get a number from user and calculate how many different triangles can be formed with the given length for example :

`5 (2-2-1)`

*Answer*: **1**

`12 (5,5,2)(3,4,5)(4,4,4)`

*Answer*: **3**

I've wrote some codes but I want a faster way to do that.
Here is my codes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int t = input.nextInt();

int value = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < t; i++) {
       for (int j = i; j < t; j++) {
           for (int h = j; h < t; h++) {
              if (i+h+j == t & i+j > h & i+h > j & h+j > i)  value++;  
           }   
       }
}

    System.out.println(value);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in O(1):

```
int n = input.nextInt();
long value = Math.round(((long)n*n)/12d) - ((long)n/4)*(((long)n + 2)/4);
```

using [Alcuin's Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlcuinsSequence.html).

Comment: some answers are negative could you please check and correct that;

Comment: @erfan.sajjadie this is due to overflow. The statement in my answer uses integer. If you want to calculate values for ns > 46000, you will have to use a bigger datatype like long.

Comment: @erfan.sajjadie I have edited it so that it should work for every positive integer n. If you want to store the number of possible triangles in an integer it will only work for (about) n < 300000, because the number of possible triangles will exceed the integer range in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it O(n^2) easily.

```
for (int i = 1; i < t; i++) {
       for (int j = i; j < t; j++) {
          int h=t-i-j;
           //check in O(1)
   }
}
```