# Improving performance of finding out how many possible triangles can be made with a given stick

Tags: python, time-complexity

I am doing an assessment that is asking by the given "n" as input which is a length of a stick; how many triangles can you make? (3 < n < 1,000,000)

For example:

```
input: N=8
output: 1
explanation:
(3,3,2)

input: N=12 
output: 3
explanation:
(4,4,4) (4,5,3) (5,5,2)
```

Now the codes I wrote are returning 33 % accuracy as the web assessment is throwing time limit error.

```
ans = 0
n = int(input())
for a in range(1, n + 1):
   for b in range(a, n - a + 1):
    c = n - a - b
    if a + b > c >= b:
        ans += 1
print(ans)
```

code b:

```
ans = 0
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n):
 for j in range(i,n):
  for c in range(j,n):
     if(i+j+c==n and i+j>c):
           ans+=1
print(ans)
```

How can this be made faster?

Comment: I don't think they're accurate though. It's not an issue of error

Comment: Why do you use range(0,n+1)?  Doesn't range(0,int(n/2)) cover all possibilities?

Comment: @JeffUK just `n // 2`, but I agree

Comment: can you please elaborate a  bit more? @jeffUK

Comment: @2020PythonNewby, you can remove an entire loop from your code. Instead of using a loop for `c`, just write `c` as the remainder of the rest, i.e. `n - i - j = c`. This removes an extra loop and should really speed up your code. EDIT: with all the other tools, this should really boost your speed and time complexity.

Comment: no side of triangle can be >= than half of the stick because to make a triangle sum of two sides should be greater than the third side, which is only possible if the longest side is strictly less than half, so you need to check lengths of sides only in range [1, n // 2)

Comment: got 30 % this time ; do i change the second for loop too ? @Matiiss

Comment: The `for b` loop can probably be avoided similarly to how you can calculate "how many numbers between 1 and 10 are smaller than 5" directly without having to check for every number.

Comment: I'm sure you could make an `O(1)` time complexity using `Alcuin's sequence` (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcuin%27s_sequence) and here are a dozen different ways of doing it: https://oeis.org/A005044

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how many different triangle can be formed with the given length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346525/how-many-different-triangle-can-be-formed-with-the-given-length)

Comment: it seems to be the exact question and @LarrytheLlama just suggested using Alcuin's sequence but not getting how it is done ..

Comment: @LarrytheLlama ; so Alcuin's sequence seems to have a better perfomance..
 form the link you sent: round(n ** 2 / 48) where does the 48 come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an intuitive O(n) algorithm I came up with:

```
def main():
  n = int(input())
  if n < 3:
    print(0)
    return
  ans = n % 2
  for a in range(2, n//2+1):
    diff = n - a
    if diff // 2 < a:
      break
    if diff % 2 == 0:
      b = diff // 2
    else:
      b = diff // 2 + 1
    b = max(b - a // 2, a)
    c = n - b - a
    if abs(b - c) >= a:
      b += 1
      c -= 1
    ans += abs(b-c)//2 + 1
  print(ans)

main()
```

I find the upper bound and lower bound for `b` and `c` and count the values in that range.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a completely different way to do it:

1. We take the smallest side and call it `a`. It can never be more than `n/3`, otherwise a different side would be the smallest.
2. We try to figure out what is the next smallest side (`b`):

   1. We see what's left after reducing our `a`.
   2. We divide it by 2 in order to find the middle where we'll start advancing from
   3. We'll see how far we can get before the difference between the lengths is `a` (or the difference from the middle is `a/2`) as that's the minimum `b` side length that is possible and satisfies `a+b>c`. Basically, the second smallest side is `a/2` less than the middle.
   4. The smallest side is the maximum between our calculation or `a`, in case`b==a`. `b` can never be lower than `a` as it violates our first rule that `a` is the smallest.
3. We figure out the difference from the middle and the smallest side. That's how many possible solutions we have for the other 2 sides.
4. Add everything together for every `a` and that's our solution.

The `floor`, `ceil` and `%` are fixes for when `a` is odd, the middle is `.5`, or `+1` in case `b+c` is even, cause `b==c` is then possible.

Code:

```
import math
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

total = 0

# a is the shortest side
for a in range(1, (n//3)+1):
    length_left = n-a
    middle_number = length_left/2
    
    # Shortest potential side b where the distance between b and c is smaller than a (c-b < a)
    b = middle_number-(math.ceil(a/2)-1)-((length_left % 2)/2)

    # We calculate how far it is from the middle
    max_distance_from_middle = middle_number - max(b, a)

    # Add another 1 if the length is even, in case b==c
    adding = math.floor(max_distance_from_middle) + (1 if length_left % 2 == 0 else 0)
    total += adding

print(total)
```

Or in an ugly one-liner:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(sum(math.floor((n-a)/2 - max((n-a)/2 - math.ceil(a/2) + 1 - (((n-a) % 2)/2), a)) + 1 - ((n-a) % 2) for a in range(1, (n//3)+1)))
```

Comment: I believe there's an issue when the output. It's close but not precise. If anyone wished to help me think about it a little more, I'd appreciate

Answer (score 1):

## Alcuin's sequence expansion: O(1)

Alcuin's sequence [See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcuin%27s_sequence] is a series expansion of the polynomial below, where the *n*th coefficient corresponds to the *n*th answer, that is, the maximum amount of unique integer triangles with perimeter `n`.

[image: Alcuin's sequence polynomial]

The algorithmic implementation of this is simply a formula. The Online Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) provides many formulas that achieve this, the simplest of which is:

- `round(n^2 / 48)` (Even)
- `round((n+3)^2 / 48)` (Odd)

[See: https://oeis.org/A005044]

This evidently has a constant time complexity, given that the only functions required are modulo 2, integer squared and round, each of which are constant time (under certain definitions).

## Implementation

Expanded:

```
def triangles(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return round(n ** 2 / 48)
    else:
        return round((n + 3) ** 2 / 48)
```

1-Liner:

```
def triangles(n): return round(n ** 2 / 48) if n%2==0 else round((n + 3) ** 2 / 48)
```

Or even:

```
def triangles(n): return round((n + 3 * n%2) ** 2 / 48)
```

## Extra

No `import`s are needed.

As the OP questioned, why do we divide by 48? While I can't answer that explicitly, let's get an intuitive understanding. We are squaring numbers, so it is evidently going to expand greatly. By the time we get to 5, that would give 64 (8^2). So, there must be a constant (albeit a reciprocal) to restrict the growth of the parabola, thus the / 48.

When we graph the OP's method, it gives an alternating parabola. This explains why there is a back-and-forth with the +3 and +0.

[image: Matplotlib graphical representation]

Answer (score 0):

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlcuinsSequence.html

```
import math
n = int(input())
print(round(n ** 2 / 48)) if n % 2 == 0 else print(round((n + 3)** 2 / 48))
```

Comment: `print` should not be part of the expression (it evaluates to `None`).